# How can I use Array instead of ArrayList to add words?

Tags: java

I have a class called Word with addWord method.

```
public class Word{

   /**constructors exits**/


   /**to addWord and return a boolean value of whether the word is successfully added or not**/
   public boolean addWord (String[] list){

   }

}


public class Test{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner;
      String[] wordList = new String[4];
      for (int i=0; i<wordList.length; i++){
         wordList[i]=input.next();
         word.addWord(wordList[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

I got

> error saying : cannot find symbol at
>
> word.addWord(wordList[i];

How can I correct it? Thanks alot!

Comment: why using array, array has static size and need a very complex method to increase their size include coping the whole array and declaring another array with larger size , so its better to use list , unless the size of your data is always constant.

Comment: I want to use ArrayList but the question ask me to use Array. That's why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not declared the word instance:

```
Word word = new Word();
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I forgot that I had already create String[] array in the Word class